# How do I save input to a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, wcf

How do I save my data to my database? I can retrieve it from my database using a wcf service, but I want to retrieve it aswell, how do I do that?

This is my service code

```
public BestuurModel GetBestuurByNaam(int id)
{
    BestuurModel result = new BestuurModel();

    return (from x in db.Persoon where x.Pers_ID == id
            select new BestuurModel
            {

                Voornaam = x.Pers_Vnaam,
                Achternaam = x.Pers_Anaam,
                Email = x.Pers_Email,
                Woonplaats = x.Pers_Woonplaats,
                Telnr = (int)x.Pers_Telnr,
                Informatie = x.Pers_Informatie,
            }).FirstOrDefault();
}

public List<BestuurModel> GetAllBestuur(int orgId)
{
    return (from x in db.Persoon

            select new BestuurModel
            {
                Voornaam = x.Pers_Vnaam,
                Achternaam = x.Pers_Anaam,
                Email = x.Pers_Email,
                Woonplaats = x.Pers_Woonplaats,
                Telnr = (int)x.Pers_Telnr,
                Informatie = x.Pers_Informatie
            }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Seems too broad. Looks like you're missing some basic lessons on how to use WCF services. I suggest googling around a bit before asking here. Your example never even shows what `db` is.

Comment: Definitely too broad. Translates into "all there is about databases please - in a page, not a book, because I am too lazy to read documentation and learn from the ground up". Show some effort - google has literally hundreds of tutorials out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using Entity Framework to save, create a new method and pass your model as parameter then add it to context and call `SaveChanges` method:

```
public void SaveToDB(BestuurModel model)
{
    // Do validation etc.
    db.persoon.Add(model); 
    db.persoon.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

I would suggest to have a look at [entity-framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx) and [wcf](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/inserting-data-into-database-using-wcf-service/) tutorials to get you started.